# Is it better to download a CSS and use it inline, or use the link to a CSS file?

Tags: html, css, jsp

On some web tutorials I've seen people download the CSS file (e.g. Bootstrap) from online, and include it as an internal CSS.

```
<link href="<c:url value='/static/css/bootstrap.min.css' />" rel="stylesheet" />
```

On others they simply include the link to it, as an external CSS.

```
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

I'm just wondering what are the pros and cons of each are?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

there are a couple pros and cons.

CDN Pros:

- It is possible the user has already downloaded it and has it cached so will not need to reload it for your site.
- faster dev time (saves like 45 seconds)
- may be, probably not - but can be, updated.

CDN Cons:

- If you host the files yourself you know they will always be available when the rest of your site is available.  --on this note, it is occasionally the case that where I work (DoD) the domain of the site I am visiting it allowed, but that of a CDN they are using is not, then the page comes in unstyled, or with no javascript running.
- may be, probably not - but can be, updated.

I personally prefer to download and serve them myself (css and js).  I remember a time when the internet was not so speedy and a whole page would wait while something remote loaded.